# Background with three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

Can anybody help me with three.js?

I need to draw background, something, like a THREE.Sprite, but it neet to be UNDER any 3d object, that will draw later. I have a camera, that can be move only on Z axis.

I tryed to use:

- cube mapping shader - PROBLEM: artefacts with shadow planes, it's unstable draw
- THREE.Sprite that dublicate camera moving - PROBLEM: artefacts with shadow plane - it have a edge highlighting OR drawing only other spirtes without objects.
- HTML DOM Background - PROBLEM: big and ugly aliasing in models.

What can I try more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try drawing in several passes, i.e. making a first render of the background scene to a buffer, and then a second one over the first "buffer". Maybe using the buffer as background (painting it in 2D with an orthographic projection, and disabling depth buffer writes in that pass).

I haven't tried it myself with three.js, but that's how I'd do that with "traditional" OpenGL.

Comment: I tried 2 cameras, first - for orthographic background (and drawed sprite on it), second -- for main scene. But renderer render only second camera view in render function.

Comment: I think you need to disable autoclear in the renderer prior to doing the second pass. Else it renders everything over the existing canvas content (which is what your first pass did).

Comment: Set the `renderDepth` property of the sprite to a very little value (-1e10 for eg): objects are normally sorted (`sortObjects` property of the renderer, which is `true` by default) and lowest renderDepth are rendered first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "3d" background i.e. something that will follow the rotation of your camera, but not react to the movement (be infinitely far), then the only way to do it is with a cubemap.

The other solution is a environment dome - a fully 3d object.

If you want a static background, then you should be able todo just a html background, i'm not sure why this would fail and what 'aliasing in models' you are talking about.